# Replacing specific character to lowercase using xsl

Tags: xslt

Hi i have an xml as below.

```
<setField identifier=”2”>
      <fieldValues>
       <fieldValue>
        <field>event</field>
        <value>
         <boundVariable>$event1</boundVariable>
        </value>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
       </fieldValue>
      </fieldValues>
      <variable>append</variable>
     </setField>
```

I need to convert to the following format.

```
<freeForm><text>append.setEvent($event1);</freeForm></text>
```

I am trying the following approach.

```
   <xsl:template match="setField" name="setFieldTemplate">
   <xsl:element name="freeForm">                    
   <xsl:element name="text">   
   <xsl:value-of select="variable" />
   <xsl:text>.set</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(field, 1, 1)"/>
   <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="boundVariable"/>
   <xsl:text>);</xsl:text>
   </xsl:element>
   </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
```

Here my requirment is based on the field name i need to generate corresponding statement as below.For that i need to change the first character of the field name to upper while generating to the following format.

append.setEvent($event1);

Here the field name is "event" and i need to generate setEvent(for which i am concatinating with the string "set").But i need to change the fieldname's first letter to upper one(Event from event).when i try with the above template with translate function i am facing some invalid xpath expression.

Please provide me some pointers to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                translate(substring(//field, 1, 1),
                'abcdefghijklmnstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
                substring(//field, 2))"/>
```

Also you might prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="setField">
    <freeForm>                    
        <text>   
            <xsl:value-of select="variable" />
            <xsl:text>.set</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                translate(
                 substring(fieldValues/fieldValue/field, 1, 1),
                 'abcdefghijklmnstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
                substring(fieldValues/fieldValue/field, 2),
                '(',fieldValues/fieldValue/value/boundVariable,');')"/>                   
        </text>
    </freeForm> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: yep the translate function can seem a bit confusing :)

Comment: @Treemonkey no alternatives if your choice is `XSLT 1.0`

Comment: I tried as below and it is working for me.                                                  <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(field|brl:field, 1, 1),'abcdefghijklmnstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
             <xsl:value-of select="substring(field|brl:field, 2)"/>                                                                   But some times i am getting <field>$event</field>($ is coming with variables in that case i need to remove the "$" if it presents). Ohterwise i am getting append.set$event($event1); instead of append.setEvent($event1);

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
                variable,
                '.set',
                translate(substring(//field, 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
                substring(//field, 2),
                '(',
                //boundVariable,
                ');'
                )"/>
```

Comment: +1 to contrast the boycotter. He might have not understood the question.